# Loop cell in range and loop in each worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Why code doesn't pick cell in next worksheet? My copy workbook contain 12 worksheets. 
`Sheet.Name = ("cat","rabbit","cow","sheep"...+8)`.

Each sheet have same headers. `Col(B1:AK1)= year(1979,1980,...2014)`.

In another folder that I repeatedly open for pasting; `File.Name = (1979.xlsx, 1980.xlsx,..,2014.xlsx)`.

In each sheet got 12 columns . `Col(B1:M1)= ("cat","rabbit","cow","sheep"...+8)`.

Each cell in range loop nicely but worksheet doesn't seem so. When my code finish run, I check paste workbook having the same data from `worksheet("cat")`.  I'm not competent with coding so please advise whenever my code can be improve.

```
Sub transferPict()

Dim wsC As Integer
Dim cell As Range
Dim Rng As Range 
Dim j, i As Long
Dim x As String
Dim Folderpath
Dim file As String    

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

wsC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For j = 1 To wsC
i = j + 1
Set Rng = Range("B1:AK1")
For Each cell In Rng
    x = cell.Value
    cell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    Folderpath = "F:\Sony Pendrive\Data Baru\Tahun\PasteTahun\"
    file = Folderpath & x & ".xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open (file)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWorkbook.Close saveChanges:=True

 Next cell
 Next j

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

At no point in your code were you specifying which worksheet you want to copy from, so it will always use the "active" sheet.

Hopefully this code will correct your issue:

```
Sub transferPict()
    Dim wsC As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    'Dim j, i As Long ' <--- This is equivalent to Dim j As Variant, i As Long
    Dim j As Long, i As Long
    Dim x As String
    Dim Folderpath
    Dim file As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    wsC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    For j = 1 To wsC
        i = j + 1
        Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j).Range("B1:AK1")
        For Each cell In Rng
            x = cell.Value
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j).Range(cell.Offset(1, 0), cell.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

            Folderpath = "F:\Sony Pendrive\Data Baru\Tahun\PasteTahun\"
            file = Folderpath & x & ".xlsx"
            Workbooks.Open file
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(2, i).PasteSpecial
            ActiveWorkbook.Close saveChanges:=True
        Next cell
    Next j

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you YowE3k,  I tried mentioning the worksheet previously, but my code running halfway with error 1004 - select method of range class failed. Unfortunately solution suggested above debug at line ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(2, i).Paste with error 438 - object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @SitiSal - sorry, the `Paste` method doesn't work on a `Range` object (such as `Cells(2, i)`) - we have to use the `PasteSpecial` method instead.  I have edited the answer.

Comment: thank you that's work. error 438 solve. Now it debug at line  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(j).Range(cell.Offset(1, 0), cell.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)).CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture error 1004.  somehow, I modify my data in copy workbook by copy & paste special -value and number formatting. Its works temporarily and debug later at the other worksheets. Do you think problem hidden in the data itself?

Comment: I replace line ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(2, i).PasteSpecial with my original code & this works fine ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Select ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i).Select ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
Thank you for your help